# Binding contained collections from Edit Action @model view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can somebody please provide code to allow [] to be used so as to save contained collection within a @model?

**Edit View:**

```
@model MVC3.Models.A

// I need to save collection values but can't use [] here to setup model binding.
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bs[0].Val)
```

**Models:**

```
public  class A
{
    public A()
    {
        this.Bs = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public  class B
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your property is an `ICollection<T>`, which doesn't provide indexed access to elements.

Change it to an `IList<T>` or just a `List<T>` and you can write your view code as it is in your first example.

If you can't change the property type for some reason, then you'll need to create a specialized view model for your particular view and then map it to the `A` model in the controller POST action.

Alternatively, it *is* possible (albeit a little awkward) to bind to *simple* collection types directly as long as you follow the proper HTML conventions, which means using multiple `input` elements with the same name, [as described by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="ints" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="8" />
```

But this only works for *simple* types, i.e. primitives or strings, not complex types like whatever `B` is in this context.

One final comment: If you're using editor templates, you can usually just bind to the entire collection and the MVC framework will figure out how to put it back together, as in just:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bs);
```

Of course this gives you no control over what goes *between* the editor templates for each item, so if you're trying to generate `<li>` elements for them or something like that, then you'll have to embed it directly into the editor template which possibly means creating a custom editor template specifically for this collection binding and using the corresponding override of `EditorFor` (the one that takes a template name).

It's a bit of a pain, but could be less work than trying to switch to a parallel-model system, if you've been sharing classes between your UI and data layers up 'til now.

Comment: Casting gives me the following error (because of the hashset for referential integrity/nodups): Cannot implicitly convert type 'HashSet<B>' to 'IList<B>'

Comment: Can you provide code for specialized View Model?  I think I know how to setup in but not sure how to assign things, save changes, etc,.?

Comment: @Mariah: That sounds like you're using the same class for your data access and your views, which isn't good practice. A view model suitable for this application would look mostly the same as the data model but using a `List<B>` instead of `ICollection<B>`, and probably without the virtual members (which aren't too useful in a UI-bound model).

Comment: Hi Aaronaught, Bs is just a collection of ints.